# Kentico, global events not firing

Tags: module, kentico

I am trying to create an event on page save, I have followed step by step [documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/custom-development/handling-global-events) and created a class in App_Code folder, I can build without any error but event is not triggering.

here is my code

```
using CMS;
using CMS.DataEngine;
using CMS.DocumentEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

[assembly: RegisterModule(typeof(ElectionEventHandler))]
public class ElectionEventHandler : Module
{
public ElectionEventHandler()
: base("CustomInithahaah")
{
}
protected override void OnInit()
{
    base.OnInit();

    // Assigns custom handlers to events
    DocumentEvents.Update.After += Update_After;
    DocumentEvents.Insert.After += Insert_After;

    ObjectEvents.Insert.After += Insert_After1;
    ObjectEvents.Update.After += Update_After1;
}

private void Update_After1(object sender, ObjectEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

private void Insert_After1(object sender, ObjectEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

private void Insert_After(object sender, DocumentEventArgs e)
{

}

private void Update_After(object sender, DocumentEventArgs e)
{

}
}
```

here is the location of my class in project.

[image]

In Pages module, I have created some pages and on the form tab of the page I am updating some values and expect these events to trigger but nothing is happening.

Comment: I checked your code and it works well for me. What should happen when you change something on form's tab? When you set breakpoints in methods and change something on forms's tab, are you jump in into breakpoint? Did you checked event logs for possible errors?

Comment: break point is not hitting, so I believe event is not registered.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a web app vs. a web site so technically there is no App_Code directory.  I believe all you need to do is build the project and your event should fire.

With a **web app**, you need to build each time you view the site.  With a **web site**, it will run the JIT compiler and compile that code automatically in the App_Code directory.

Comment: I am building the project every time I make any change, I am trying to see if break point hits but nothing is happening. On the forms table I just edit few field and pressed save button, Is that enough to trigger the event?

Comment: Make sure your web.config is set to debug=true

Comment: I have debug=true, I can debug other customization.